# Select and Read on stdin returns only one char on first enter, but more on second enter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read from stdin in Python 3. My code works as expected, but on the first read I get less data than expected: When I start the script and type "Test" ( = keypress), I get only the 'T'. When I press  again, I get 'est\n\n'.

I would expect to read 'Test\n' on the first  and '\n' on the second .

If I send Test\n a second Time, I get the same behavior.

Script:

```
import sys
import select


def read(size=0):
    '''
    read data from stdin, may return less the size

    :param size: max size to read, on 0 or None read as much as available
    '''
    data = bytearray()
    while size == 0 or size < len(data):
        rlist, dummy, dummy = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.1)
        if rlist:
            data = data + sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
        else:
            return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(1):
        data = read()
        if data:
            print("data returned from read:", data)
```

This online example shows the behavior as well: https://repl.it/repls/EnragedMaturePlanes

Comment: You seem to be expecting `read()` to read *lines*. It doesn't work that way, it operates at the byte level. You have to assemble the input into what you consider to be lines. You can call `readlines()` which behaves closer to what you expect, but it will not return until you indicate end-of-file by typing control-z.

Comment: No, I'm expecting it to read single bytes.
I know stdin is buffered, so I should expect my input after I press <Enter>. But currently when I press the Enter Button, I get just the first letter. From my understanding, the select call should return readable rlists for all chars of my input (which I assemble into the data buffer).